# PHP POST/GET request encrypted

Tags: php, url, encryption, openssl, communication

I need to send sensitive data through a url like following.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/handlingfile.php?username="abc"&password="pass"&BankAccount="0983479"
```

What is the best way to encrypt the parameter values in order to have a secure communication?

Answer (score 8):

- Do not fuss around with browser encryption, switch to https for save transport. That is what is was 'invented' for. For a few dollars a year you can [buy a certificate](http://ssl.comodo.com/index.php?key5sk1=b6a407ee80fecb5c8af545524e90a0583449b316&key5sk2=2128&key5sk3=1346844637000&key5sk4=2128&key5sk5=1346844645000&key5sk6=1904&key5sk7=1346844657000&key6sk1=&key6sk2=CH210118089&key6sk3=7&key6sk4=nl-nl&key6sk5=NL&key6sk6=0&key6sk7=Google&key6sk8=11331&key6sk9=16801050&key6sk10=true&key6sk11=90463528d44a0bbabc54cd37bb7657a75d8859d8&key6sk12=2032&key7sk1=2&key7sk2=196112&key1sk1=ors&key1sk2=Google). It gives your users a 'safe environment' feeling when there is a 'lock' icon displayed in the browser.
- Do not send your username and password in the url, but use a post action in your form.
- Consider using oAuth service, so users login with facebook or google account. You do not need to store the credentials at al, just the token you receive from oAuth.

Comment: Post request with a Plain Password is not a good approach at all, for hackers there is no difference between a GET and a POST

Comment: @Ummar Although I agree in principle, my browser has this funny thing called "browser history". It shows complete URL's. It doesn't show complete POST requests. So yes, it doesn't help against hackers sniffing a connection, but it does help from hiding your data from, say, a roommate.

Comment: @Ruwan Dissanayaka - Then even more you should use SSL. Url's are easy to intercept, and it's as easy to send the encrypted password to your application without SSL.

Answer (score 1):

Use **SSL**, its the right way of encrypting data between client and server requests.

The other way might be to store the encrypted passwords and bankaccount number in database using One way encryption like `MD5` or `SHA1`, and pass encrypted passwords and bank account in URL with same encryption and match them from database.

But again the best is using **SSL**

Comment: Your other way is a bad solution, the password-hash would simply replace the password. It would be easy to intercept the URL with the password-hash, and use it to gain access.

Comment: @martinstoeckli, but at least your password is not in plain text and your other accounts using the same password would be safe, but I have said already the **SSL** solution is best.

Comment: Yes i saw the hint about SSL, i only wanted to point out that the option is not really an option. To protect the password with a hash, you should at least use `bcrypt` with a unique salt, MD5 and SHA1 can be brute forced ways too fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
use
urlencode
and
rawurldecode
```

You can also encrypt data using javascript with your own algorithm. But none of these secure

Comment: Just to clarify, neither of these are encryption algorithms. Use SSL, and preferably POST rather than GET. Oh and hash details in the database.